# How do I check if a variable exists before I set a form value equal to it in Jade: Template Engine

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to set the value of a username form equal to the previously entered username if it exists in jade.

```
 input.box(type = "text" name = "username"  placeholder = "Username" value=`${username}`)
```

My current code looks like this but if I don't pass in a value for username, the value is set to undefined. How do I implement a check to see if the variable exists before the value is set to the username variable?
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to do this:

```
value= username ? username : 'no username'
```

In this case `undefined` is going to evaluate to `false` and trigger the second option in the ternary statement.

Also note that you don't need to use `${}` when you're inside a pug element.

```
input.box(value=`${username}`)
```

will produce the same output as

```
input.box(value= username)
```

The second one is far easier to understand quickly.